# fusion charts features

Tags: flash, fusioncharts

i've got a few issues with my charts that i didnt find documentation about

1. I have a 3d pie chart that can be transformed in animation to 2d, when picking "view 2d" option from the pop-up menu. can I trigger this action through JS code?
   the onlinr documentation only refers "MSCombi3D.swf" chart type. I tryed applying the code in the example on my pie chart but it doesnt recognize : myChart.view2D()
2. Is there a way to control the location of the data values, in a line chart? (below or above the line).now the values appear above and below randomly
3. can i control the speed of bars movement in a bar chart when it loads?

Answer (score 1):

1 & 2 It is not possible.

3. You would need to use Animation Styles with "_xScale" property & set the duration attribute as you desire to control the speed. (refer to: http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/Contents/Styles/Animation.html )

Answer (score 0):

1) Of course you can. Using JQuery Framework you can do basically anything you want with JS, including changing your chart type.  Check JS-based FS also to make an easier integration.

2) I'm almost sure you can't.  This kind of questions are better suited for FS support directly.  If there is a way they'd know.